# responsive web design - @media screen guidance

Tags: html, css

I am trying to teach myself responsive web design, but I don't at all understand how I can do this -.-

When my browser is 1200px width or more, obviously I have centered it to sit in the middle along with everything else, but when I make it smaller, this row/section is not modifying itself. I have mucked around with @media screen etc, but i cant get it to work. Could someone please help me get this to work?

[image]

[image]

The code for this row is:

```css
.row-circles {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 450px;
    line-height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1263px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.steve1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 406px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 390px;

}
.steve2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 406px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 390px;
}
.quentin {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 406px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 390px;
}

.quentin h2 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.steve1 h2 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.steve2 h2 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.quentin p {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.steve1 p {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.steve2 p {

    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}


.img-circle {
    border-bottom-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-image-outset: 0px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    border-image-slice: 100%;
    border-image-source: none;
    border-image-width: 1;
    border-left-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    border-left-style: none;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    border-right-style: none;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-top-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: inline;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 140px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 140px;
}
.img-circle img {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0;
}
.circles h2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 456px;
}
.circles p {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 436px;
}
a.btn.btn-default {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    background-color: #83d3c9;
    background-image: none;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-image-outset: 0px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    border-image-slice: 100%;
    border-image-source: none;
    border-image-width: 1;
    border-left-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 200;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 111.031px;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-container">

                <div class="row-circles">
                    <div class="steve2">
                        <img class="img-circle" src="images/profile2.jpg" alt="Steven Scott" width="140" height="140">
                        <h2><strong>Steven Scott</strong></h2>
                        <p>Trade experience:
                            <br>20+ Years - Fitting & Machining.</p>
                        <br>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Background »</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="steve1">
                        <img class="img-circle" src="images/profile1.png" alt="Steven Muscat" width="140" height="140">
                        <h2><strong>Steven Muscat</strong></h2>
                        <p>Trade experience:
                            <br>20+ Years - Fitting & Machining.</p>
                        <br>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Background »</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="quentin">
                        <img class="img-circle" src="images/profile3.jpg" alt="Quentin Bailey" width="140" height="140">
                        <h2><strong>Quentin Bailey</strong></h2>
                        <p>Trade experience:
                            <br>4<sup>th</sup> Year Apprentice - Fitting & Machining.</p>
                        <br>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Background »</a>

                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

If I change the width to 100%, it shows vertically:

[image]

Container:

[image]

[image]

As this is a bootstrap, most of the responsiveness is already working, and everything is using media queries.

Comment: Maybe try to set the width and height?

Comment: yeah but how? I don't know how to.. :/

Comment: no :-( , somone will probably get the solution soon. Or i will start a bounty for you :-)

Comment: just to clarify: do you want the three sections to stack on mobile devices and then be side-by-side once the screen width is at 1200px?

Comment: I want the three sections to stay side by side, no matter what platform it is viewed on. All I really want is the 3 sections to get smaller as the windows width is smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

All you have to do is set the width of your child containers to `width: 33.33%`. and set the width of your `.row-circles` to `max-width` so that it decreases depending on the view port, but always stays within 1263px if viewport size if more than that.

One thing i forgot to say is to `never write repetitive code` if different elements (classes IDs etc) use the same attributes then put them under the same class, or group the together like i did below.

```css
.row-circles {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 450px;
    line-height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1263px; /* new */
    margin: 0 auto;

}


.steve1, .steve2, .quentin {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 100%;
    height: 406px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33.3%; /* new */

}

.steve1 h2, .steve2 h2, .quentin h2 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}


.quentin p, .steve p, .quentin p {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

/*NEW*/
img.img-circle {
    min-width: 50px;/*NEW*/
    max-width: 140px;/*NEW*/
    width: 100%;/*NEW*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-image-outset: 0px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    border-image-slice: 100%;
    border-image-source: none;
    border-image-width: 1;
    border-left-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    border-left-style: none;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    border-right-style: none;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-top-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    border-top-style: none;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: inline;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Deleted
img .img-circle {
  ..... /*Deleted/*
  }
*/

.circles h2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 456px;
}
.circles p {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 436px;
}
a.btn.btn-default {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    background-color: #83d3c9;
    background-image: none;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-image-outset: 0px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    border-image-slice: 100%;
    border-image-source: none;
    border-image-width: 1;
    border-left-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 200;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 111.031px;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-container">

                <div class="row-circles">
                    <div class="steve2">
                        <img class="img-circle" src="images/profile2.jpg" alt="Steven Scott" width="140" height="140">
                        <h2><strong>Steven Scott</strong></h2>
                        <p>Trade experience:
                            <br>20+ Years - Fitting & Machining.</p>
                        <br>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Background »</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="steve1">
                        <img class="img-circle" src="images/profile1.png" alt="Steven Muscat" width="140" height="140">
                        <h2><strong>Steven Muscat</strong></h2>
                        <p>Trade experience:
                            <br>20+ Years - Fitting & Machining.</p>
                        <br>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Background »</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="quentin">
                        <img class="img-circle" src="images/profile3.jpg" alt="Quentin Bailey" width="140" height="140">
                        <h2><strong>Quentin Bailey</strong></h2>
                        <p>Trade experience:
                            <br>4<sup>th</sup> Year Apprentice - Fitting & Machining.</p>
                        <br>
                        <p>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Background »</a>

                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: @wogwog could you you tell me what exactly is it you want to do...?
Maybe you could just set your `width` to `max-width:  1263px`

Comment: I want the three sections to stay side by side, no matter what platform it is viewed on. All I really want is the 3 sections to get smaller as the windows width is smaller.

Comment: You should have said so from the beginning.. Check my edit

Comment: Yeah, that works! However it does get a bit messy (overlaps), is there anyway I could make it so that the circles maybe get smaller as well as the text so that it evenly fits? Or could you think of any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I added some example media queries to this codepen so you can see how to change specific parts of the design for different screen sizes. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWMeKg

Comment: @wogwog there you go.. Marked added parts as `/*NEW**/ and i deleted some repetitive code as well.. set it as `/*DELETED*/

Comment: Don't forget to choose the best answer. Since people will never know if the questions was answered if you don't choose one.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is (as you commented above) to keep steve, steve, and quentin always side-by-side, no matter the size of the screen, here's the css: (I've combined rules for steve1, steve2, and quentin as they were identical)

view codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWMeKg

```
.row-circles {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 450px;
    line-height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width:100%; 
    max-width:1263px; 
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.steve1, .steve2, .quentin {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 406px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
}
.quentin h2, .steve1 h2, .steve2 h2 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.quentin p, .steve1 p, .steve2 p {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

If you need to change certain aspects of this styling for different screens (for instance, you'll likely need to edit the height of the sections on smaller screens, font-size, etc.), then you can wrap those differences in @media rules.
- personally, I would start with how you want things to appear on the smallest screens, and then use min-width rules to change things as necessary as screen size increases. for example:

```
/* rules that apply to everything */
.steve1, .steve2, .quentin {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px; 
    height: auto;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
 }

/* example rule that changes based on screen size */
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
.steve1, .steve2, .quentin {
    font-size:18px;
    height:406px;
  }
}
```